# How to add form action to laravel function

Tags: laravel

I have a website I am currently editing tht was built with laravel. I have have a page that displays a "details of shipped package"

I added a form to page to update the current location of the shipped package on the details page.

```
<div class="row mb-30">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mt-2">
                <div class="card border--dark">
                    <h5 class="card-header bg--dark">@lang('Courier Location')</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{route('....')}}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="current_location" class="form-control-label font-weight-bold">@lang('Current Location')</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="current_location" value="{{__($courierInfo->current_location)}}" required="">
                                    </div>
            
                                    
            
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-paper-plane"></i>@lang('Update')</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have also added the update function in the controller

```
public function courierUpdate(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'current_location' => 'required',
        ]);
        $courierInfoUpdate =CourierInfo::findOrFail($id);
        $courierInfoUpdate->current_location = $request->current_location;
        
        $courierInfoUpdate->save();
        $notify[] = ['success', 'Courier location info has been updated'];
        return back()->withNotify($notify);
    }
```

I am having problem with the laravel route to call that should be added as form action.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new route in `routes/web.php`

```
//import your controller at Beginning of the file
use App\Http\Controllers\YourController;

Route::post('update_location/{id}', [YourController::class, 'courierUpdate'])->name('updateLocation');
//or
Route::post('update_location/{id}', 'YourController@courierUpdate')->name('updateLocation');
```

And then in your blade view

```
<form action="{{ route('updateLocation', [ 'id' => $id]) }}" method="POST">
 @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: I am getting the same error

Route [updateLocation] not defined. (View: /home/somename/example.com/core/resources/views/admin/courier/details.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a route on the web.php
Route::post('/courier-Update/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\YourControllerName@courierUpdate')->name('courier.Update');

and now just call this route in your form and also pass the id of that courier
like this:
route('courier.Update',$courier->id)

Comment: Route [courier.Update] not defined. (View: /home/somename/example.com/core/resources/views/admin/courier/details.blade.php)

I get this error

Comment: check after running this command "php artisan optimize"